# ObjectUnsunscriberError Implementation when using async pipe and subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, observable, subject

I am using async pipe to display several forms based on the user options, I am using Subject and Async pipe to generate form dynamically. It is working but I am getting following console errors:

Template :

```
     <div *ngIf="observable">
        <form-builder [config]="observable"
          [config$]="subject$" [formGroup]="formGroup">
        </form-builder>
      </div>
</div>
```

Component

```
this.observable$ = this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      map((control: string) => {
        if (!control) {
          this.subject$.unsubscribe();
          return null;   //// When I dont return null its not giving error
        }

        if (this.subject$.closed) {
          this.subject$ = new Subject<
            FormBuilderConfig
          >();
        }

        this.subject$.next(newFormBuilderConfig);
        return newFormBuilderConfig;
      })
    );
```

Console ERRORS :

```
Error Occurred while building and resolving component from factory.  TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined
    at FormBuilderComponent.push


 ObjectUnsubscribedErrorImpl {message: "object unsubscribed", name: "ObjectUnsubscribedError", ngDebugContext: DebugContext_, ngErrorLogger: ƒ}
    message: "object unsubscribed"
    name: "ObjectUnsubscribedError"
    ngDebugContext: DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 2, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
    ngErrorLogger: ƒ ()
    __proto__: Error
```

Comment: The `valueChanges` error appears to be because you are trying to subscribe to the `valueChanges` of a `FormControl` before it is initialised…